# Retornar a pessoa mais velha de uma lista com tuplos

Tags: python, lista, tuple

A pergunta é a seguinte ;

Considere que uma pessoa tem o formato tuplo - (nome,ano de nascimento,cidade).

Crie uma função maisvelho que receba uma lista de pessoas e retorne a pessoa mais velha do grupo.

Estou perdido neste código alguém me consegue ajudar ?

tenho as seguintes listas;

```
pessoa=[("pedro",1999,"porto"),("pedro2",2020,"feira"),("pedro3",2002,"sjm")]

velho=[("pedr22o",2000,"porto22")]

for i in pessoa:
    for x in velho:
        if i[1] < x[1]:
            velho = i
print(velho)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) para pegar a tupla que tem o menor ano de nascimento utilizando o parâmetro `key` da função.

```
from operator  import itemgetter

pessoas = [
    ("pedro", 1999, "porto"),
    ("pedro2", 2020, "feira"),
    ("pedro3", 2002, "sjm"),
]

velho = min(pessoas, key=itemgetter(1))

print(velho)  # ("pedro", 1999, "porto")
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-359191-6333) com o código funcionando.</sup>

---

Acima utilizei o operador [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) do módulo `operator` para facilitar, mas o seguinte código faz a mesma coisa:

```
def itemgetter(n_item):
    def getter(tupla):
        return tupla[n_item]
    return getter

pessoas = [
    ("pedro", 1999, "porto"),
    ("pedro2", 2020, "feira"),
    ("pedro3", 2002, "sjm"),
]

velho = min(pessoas, key=itemgetter(1))

print(velho)  # ("pedro", 1999, "porto")
```

`itemgetter` retorna uma função que sempre pega o item `n` do parâmetro recebido, nesse caso uma tupla mas poderia ser uma lista ou qualquer classe que implemente o método [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Answer (score 5):

Não precisa percorrer `velho`, e nem precisa ser uma lista.

```
pessoa=[("pedro",1999,"porto"),("pedro2",2020,"feira"),("pedro3",2002,"sjm")]
velho=("pedr22o",2000,"porto22")

for i in pessoa:
    if i[1] < velho[1]:
        velho = i
print(velho)
```

Ali vc estava atribuindo uma tupla a uma lista.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado nas condições para a resposta implementei a solução para o problema. Crei que não há a necessidade de explicar o código porque ele já está todo comentado. Mas para qualquer dúvida ,estarei aqui.

```
# Lista de pessoas
pessoas = [
  ("pedro" ,1999 ,"porto") ,
  ("paulo" ,2016 ,"feira de santana") ,
  ("jonatha" ,2002 ,"simao dias") ,
  ("roberto" ,1987 ,"salvador")
]
def mais_velha(pessoas):
  """
  Função respossável por retornar a pessoa
  mais velha de uma lista.

  Esta função recebe apenas um argumento ,que é
  uma lista contendo tuplas que armazenam
  informações como:
    nome       - nome da pessoa
    nascimento - data do nascimento da pessoa
    cidade     - cidade atual onde vive a pessoa.

  A partir do argumento da funcão ela reordena
  a lista para que a pessoa mais velha (com
  nascimento mais antigo) seja a primeira da lista.
  """

  # Variável que auxilia na organização
  # da ordem das pessoas.
  aux = None

  # For loops responsaveis por toda a organização
  # da ordem das pessoas.
  for pessoa_x in range(0 ,len(pessoas) ,1):
    for pessoa_y in range(0 ,len(pessoas) ,1):
      # Teste e possível troca da ordem das pessoas
      # testando a cada interação se a pessoa anteriar
      # (pessoa_x) é mais nova que a pessoa atual
      # (pessoa_y).
      if pessoas[pessoa_x][1] < pessoas[pessoa_y][1]:
        aux = pessoas[pessoa_x]
        pessoas[pessoa_x] = pessoas[pessoa_y]
        pessoas[pessoa_y] = aux

  # Retorno da primeira pessoa da lista ,
  # a mais velha.
  return pessoas[0]

# Exibe a pessoa mais velha ,"roberto"
print(mais_velha(pessoas))
```